# htmlagilitypack c#

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

проблема в том что AllNodes не получает никакого значения, возможно неправильно указан xPath? или

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmldoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        public string Url;
        public void DownlodHtmlDocument()
        {
            var web = new HtmlWeb();
            htmldoc = web.Load(Url);
        }
        public void GetHrefAds()
        {
            HtmlNodeCollection AllNodes = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("*[@class='lheight22 margintop5']/a");
            foreach (var MensaNode in AllNodes)
            {
                string HrefAtt = MensaNode.GetAttributeValue("href", "not found");
                MessageBox.Show(HrefAtt);
            }
        }
```

Comment: ну так проверь xpath в каком-то плагине для браузера которым пользуешся. Или хотя бы код xml/html -а кидай вместе с вопросом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в Google Chrome:

1. открываете сайт
2. нажимаете F12
3. выбираете элемент на странице
4. кликаете на нем в разметке правой кнопкой мыши
5. копируете XPath

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для Firefox：

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: проблема была в xPath, спасибо я ее решил, только этот способ мне не помог