# С# Как спарсить адреса изображений с классом со страницы сайта?

Tags: c#, парсер

Мне нужно спарсить изображения определенного класса со страницы и разместить их в WinForms.

Хочу для начала получить список адресов изображений, чтобы затем их добавить.

С AngleSharp не получилось, не помню почему - возможно причина та же самая. Запутался.

Пробую с HtmlAgilityPack. Если делаю `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");` - он ищет совсем мало картинок. И есть такое ощущение, что это те картинки, которые находятся непросредственно в коде страницы. Как если бы смотреть ее исходник, а не открывать панель разработчика.

А картинки, которые нужны - имеют класс и висят примерно в `...>div>div>div>a>var>img.` - таких структурах.

Нагуглил, что вроде как для моих целей надо открывать StreamReader, закачивать себе страницу и потом ее парсить.

Верно ли это? Какая библиотека лучше с этим справится?

p.s. Я пробовал искать с классом и не находил ничего, поэтому попробовал вообще все картинки найти.

Вот код, которым проверяю:

```
    var web = new HtmlWeb();
    var doc = web.Load(url);
    var imgs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@class=\"postImg\"]");

    if (imgs == null) {
        Console.WriteLine("Массив пустой.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        return; }
```

Comment: [как парсить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/752593/179763), как [получить xpath](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/988855/179763)

Comment: xpathhelper - расширение для хрома. Откройте сайт, запустите расширение и тестируйте там свои запросы. Если бы показали страницу, с которой надо парсить, можно было бы сказать точнее. Вполне может быть, что ваши изображения подгружаются не сразу, поэтому вы их и не видите все.

Comment: @АндрейФедоров Спасибо. Вот, к примеру с рутрекера страничка. http://rutracker.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=381935  Там последняя фотка под спойлером, кот на дереве. Перед включением проги конечно vpn включаю, ибо блок. Расширение находит по //img[@class="postImg"] этот элемент, а программа - нет. Добавил код в вопрос.

Comment: @keltkelt попробуйте //var[@class='postImg']

Comment: @АндрейФедоров Спасибо, первый рубеж прошло... 1) А как это вы сделали?  2) Теперь пытаюсь получить ссылку arrayItem.Attributes["src"].Value - выкидывает ошибку NullReferenceException.

Comment: @keltkelt Нужно смотреть html-код, который вы загружаете в HAP. Потому как в браузере иногда элементы иначе отображаются, нежели там. Со списком лучше работать вот так: foreach (var i in arrayItem) { MessageBox.Show(i.GetAttributeValue("src", ""));} Это, конечно, при условии, что он у вас не пустой

Comment: В url адрес той страницы, которую я написал. Вы же этот код имели в виду?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95534/discussion-between-keltkelt-and--).

Comment: @АндрейФедоров Последний вопрос) Нужно ли один раз сделать new HtmlWeb(), и потом его использовать для всех  web.Load страниц, в Task итд? Или для каждой задачи надо это код прописывать и вызывать его отдельно?