# Составить XPath для Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

Задача найти нужного вновь созданного пользователя по тексту и кликнуть по нему. Должен быть клик по элементу с классом list-item list-item-station ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle. XPath у меня всегда разный! Я знаю логин,который создаю сам!
XPath имеет вид:

```html
//*[@id="applicationHost"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[62]
```

При создании меняется цифра в последнем div.
Сейчас делаю так:

```html
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'will-edit will-edit-input will-edit-textarea')][contains(text(),'Логин')]")).Click();
```

html:

```html
<div class="list-item list-item-station ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">
    <div class="operations">
        <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-image image-item">
        <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="icon-name editable-input-long">
        <span class="will-edit will-edit-input will-edit-textarea">ФИО</span><textarea class="editable-  textarea"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [это?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/988855/179763)

Comment: Уточню,что хpath всегда разный. Знаю ФИО.

Comment: На какой ответ вы тогда расчитываете? Какой бы XPath вам не предложили, он будет не актуален, так как он всегда разный, верно?

Comment: Я не знаю все возможности Selenium. Мне нужно создать нового пользователя и дать ему права. В веб интерфейсе у меня всё получилось кроме этого. Xpath  всегда разный. Я знаю только логин,который у меня в переменной.

Comment: Может я могу получить все xpath по определённому критерию для записи в массив. Потом сравнить два массива и получить пользователя,который вновь создан для клика по нему?

Comment: Возможности селениума тут не при чем, если у вас каждый раз разметка сайта разная, то вы либо не сможете ничего сделать, либо будете писать код, привязанный к алгоритму генерации разметки вашего конкретного сайта.

Comment: Код не меняется.Сервер электронной очереди.Автоматизирую добавление нового пользователя в систему с добавлением галок на роли.

Comment: Ну это специфично для вашего сайта. Никто, кроме разработчикоа вашего сайта не знает, как этот сайт работает.

Answer (score 1):

> Должен быть клик по элементу с классом list-item list-item-station ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle.

Selenium-ный поиск по xpath не поддерживает поиск по computed propertys. Это нужно обходить следующим синтаксисом:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".class1Name.class2Name.class3Name"));
```

то есть:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".list-item.list-item-station.ui-draggable.ui-draggable-handle"));
```

теоретически должен найти нужный элемент

Вторым вариантом, конкретно через xpath можно сделать вот так:

```
IWebElement button = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'list-item')] AND [contains(@class,'list-item-station)]);
```

это приблизительно, т.к. я давно не использовал и не могу наверняка вспомнить. Но подход именно этот.

Обрати внимание что я не заполнял полностью xpath-пример. То есть допиляй под себя его и внеси нужные изменения, это был просто пример!

---

Следующее: сайт в любом случае имеет ограниченное количество вариантов где может высветить имя созданного пользователя. И этих мест будет вряд ли больше 10. Это значит что на каждый вариант нужно будет написать свой селектор и проверять нету ли элемента по даному селектору на странице.

И последнее:

никогда не используй автоматически сгенеррированные икспасы вида:

```
//*[@id="applicationHost"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[62]
```

это "дно" которое будет ломатся при каждом чихе.

Ты должен сам научится писать оптимально выглядящие селекторы, а не генерить их при помощи девтулс или xpath плагинов под браузер.

Answer (score -1):

Я нашёл для своей ситуации следующее решение:

```html
IWebElement child = Browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(@class,'will-edit will-edit-input will-edit-textarea')][contains(text(),'"+name+"')]"));
child.FindElement(By.XPath("../..")).Click();
```

Спасибо всем за помощь.

Comment: этот код перестанет работать в случае если любой из классов внутри компьютед класса переместится влево или вправо. А это случается время от времени. Как это обойти написано в моем ответе. Настоятельно не советую использовать даный xpath.